# DevExpress gridView for Data Input only

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Hi I have created a Banded Grid View using GridControl Designer in WinForms(for this sake of avoiding to code manually), like [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/i/features/winforms-grid-banded-grid-view.png). I do not want to bind this grid to any Data Source and use it to take input only on run time from the user by adding multiple rows and then transfer the data to a datatable or the database. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I believe that the GridControl from DevExpress cannot work without a datasource. You need at least a BindingList to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a dataset structure corresponding to created BandedGridView (for example one DataTable with a columns which names corresponding to your column.FieldName), who assign to the grid.DataSource. Set Grid to allow the user to enter new lines etc. On runtime when you want to move data from the CONTROL  you just pick up the filled DataSet in grid.DataSource and save into database manually.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This solved my problem like a charm.